# Can I use a Rasp Pi 3 B+ for Home automation and camera hub?

Tags: camera, home-automation

I'm currently investigating a setup to start in home automation and security. Since this question touch a lot of topic, don't hesitate to let me know where I can ask them as I'm not sure myself.

My current plan is to use a Raspberry Pi 3 B Plus with a Z-Wave USB device and Home Assistant for the OS.

I would like to have a night cam indoor to help me monitor my pets (cats, aquariums) while I'm away in case something happens (peace of mind is my main goal, second is future-proofing). My ultimate goal is to have a kind of all-in-one security/home automation solution.

I found the Arlo cameras which require a hub. It would require more upfront cost;
Also, linking a camera by wifi and monitoring a rtps stream from Home Assistant on the Pi would require a lot of CPU I suppose.

- Do I need a hub just for the cameras?
- Is the Raspberry powerful enough to read multiple camera streams and send the  streams to a nas when movement is detected for example? 720p or 1080p...

Future need may require some sort of face detection for in home presence or object detection, etc... still looking for a lib and a way to achieve this, the little berry wouldn't support it.

For those having a similar setup, what is your indoor current camera? If you could reply in comments (as the answer is subjective and doesn't have a "good" answer)

Thanks for your help in my adventure as I discover the beauty and complexity of this world.

Comment: `Do I need a hub just for the cameras?` can the cameras work without a Hub ... "cameras" is very vague ... even Arlo cameras isn't good enough, since there's multiple models - and surely you can read what is required for each model, if it only talks to the hub, then a hub you'll most likely need

Comment: Seems you already have taken the [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour). But to elaborate it a bit, this site isn't made for brainstorming and discuss general issues. It is made to do one specific question that can be answered detailed.

Comment: Ok thanks @Ingo :) Any good site where I can discuss this?

Comment: I would suggest to use https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/